# The code compiles, but all my answers come out to be 0

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The code compiles, but all my answers come out to be 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;// use the Scanner class located in the "java.util" directory

public class Assignment2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)//main method that runs the program using methods below
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[100];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count;
        int c=0;
        do  
        {
            count = input.nextInt();
            c++;       
        } while (count != 0 && c < numbers.length);

        double min = findMin(numbers, numbers.length);
        int countNeg = countNegative(numbers, numbers.length);
        double sum = computePositiveSum(numbers, numbers.length);
        System.out.println("The minimum number is " +min);
        System.out.println("The sum of the positive numbers is $" +countNeg) ;
        System.out.println("The total number of negative numbers is " +sum);
    }

    public static double findMin(double[] numbers, int count) //finds and displays the minimum input value
    {
        double min = numbers[0];
        for(count =1; count<numbers.length; count++)
        {
            if(numbers[count] <min)
            {
                min = numbers[count];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
    public static int countNegative (double[] numbers, int count) //counts the number of times a negative number is added to the array
    {
        int countNeg =0;
        for (count = 0; count < numbers.length; count++)
        {
            if(numbers[count] < 0)
            {
                countNeg = countNeg + 1;
            }   
        }
        return countNeg;
    }

    public static double computePositiveSum(double[] numbers, int count)//calculates the sum of the positive integers in the array
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for(count=0; count<numbers.length; count++)
        {
            if(numbers[count] > 0)
            {
                sum = sum + numbers[count];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you filling 'numbers'?

Comment: A general tip: all of your function arguments named "count" are unnecessary.  You can just declare count to be a local variable to the method, as "count" is solely used as a loop counter (and not the array length).

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the entered values to the array `numbers`. Add this

```
numbers[c] = count;
```

inside the `do-while` loop:

```
do {
    count = input.nextInt();
    numbers[c] = count;
    c++;
} while (count != 0 && c < numbers.length);
```

**Note** that if you just input positive *(> 0)* numbers and don't fill the whole array `numbers`, `findMin()` will return `0`, because it is the default value for the elements of the array.

**Edit:**

I would say that the print statement

```
System.out.println("The sum of the positive numbers is $" + countNeg);
System.out.println("The total number of negative numbers is " + sum);
```

are not coherent with the methods called. It should be:

```
System.out.println("The sum of the positive numbers is " + sum);
System.out.println("The total number of negative numbers is " + countNeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        double[] numbers = new double[100];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count;
        int c=0;
        do  
        {
            count = input.nextDouble();
            numbers[c] = count;
            c++;       
        } while (count != 0 && c < numbers.length);
```

This code should work. You have to add the numbers to the array which you are entering through stdin

```
double[] numbers = new double[100];
```

Here you are initializing the array with all 0.0 elements. You want to take input int he array from stdin?

Answer (score 0):

You don't put anything into numbers array so they are all 0. The corrected code is this:

```
    do  
    {
        numbers[c] = input.nextDouble();
        c++;       
    } while (numbers[c] != 0 && c < numbers.length);
```